# Is there a simple WCF example online that uses MSMQ?

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have to do a small introductory presentation for my WCF Intro class (for my fellow students). :D

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a simple WCF/MSMQ application? Something **dead-basic** so I don't overwhelm everyone and myself. We're just learning this stuff. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example I've always used - which seems to be the most thorough public available example - is [SOA'izing MSMQ and WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/msmqpluswcf).

It's not really 'dead-basic', though.  You need to have a grasp of both WCF and MSMQ before you will really understand what's going on.

Assuming you have a reasonable understanding of WCF, I'd suggest you create your own example.  Essentially you create a basic WCF service, but change the binding from HTTP to MSMQ.

For a WCF intro class, do a demo of a http-based WCF service.  Do you really need to demo the different bindings?  Although MSMQ binding works the same, it is 'trickier' than HTTP binding.

**edit:**  I've found another nice sample from Dennis van der Stelt called [WCF and MSMQ](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/02/28/wcf-and-msmq.aspx).  It covers the MSMQ specific configuration in simple steps.